# file read in ruby getting output as spaces in character

Tags: ruby

I have an function to read data from file but I have problem with reading data

input in file:
**1,S1­-88,S2­-53,S3­-69,S4­-64**

```
File.open(file_path).each do |line|
    p line.gsub(/\s+/, "")
end
```

Output:
   **"1,S1 ­-88,S2 ­-53,S3 ­-69,S4­ -64 \n"**

The problem is, it adding an extra space after s1 -integer,s2 -integer like so, I have tried .gsub(/\s+/, "") to remove white space from string but it is not working, Please can any one help me why this happenning, How I can override this issue Or it may be file encoding issue?

Comment: Can you describe what you're trying to do? What is the expected output? `line` should be a string and yet you're calling `join` on it as though its an array. Does this code even run?

Comment: Why do you need UTF-16 ?

Comment: @Genzume Sorry, I have updated the question I want output should be similar to input, but it adding an extra space before hypen(-), example s1  -23

Comment: @lacostenycoder, I thought it would be encoding problem that's y I tried with some encoding types

Comment: Not sure if StackOverflow does some weird things with formatting, but your input seems to contain an "invisible" character (U+00AD SOFT HYPHEN) before each hyphen.  Try `.gsub(/[\s\u00ad]+/, "")`, maybe that works.

Comment: @Jyrki Thanks, Its worked!....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you binread, essentially you have UTF-8 characters in between

```
irb(main):013:0> f = File.binread('f2.txt')
=> "1,S1\xC2\xAD-88,S2\xC2\xAD-53,S3\xC2\xAD-69,S4\xC2\xAD-64"
```

[`\xC2\xAD`](http://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?start=128&number=128&names=-&utf8=string-literal) are essentially whitespace characters

This may be because you have copied it from somewhere incorrectly or it was introduced in your text because of God. Don't know. [You an check here](https://www.soscisurvey.de/tools/view-chars.php), it shows there are hidden characters in between your text.

This will remove all characters not wanted.

```
File.foreach('f2.txt') do |f|
 puts f.gsub(/[^\\s!-~]/, '')
end

=> 1,S1-88,S2-53,S3-69,S4-64
```